# Problem with deserialization of String sent over wire with XStream

Tags: java, web-services, xml-serialization, apache-axis, xstream

I am trying to create a simple webservice which takes a String as input and returns string as output.
I am using Ecelipse Helios and Axis 2.15.

1. I am writing simple WSDL for the same.
2. I am generating the stubs using code generator.

   > New ->code generator -> java class from wsdl-> give WSDL and generates the java skeletons.
3. And in the skelton I am just print the value what is coming as parameter.  and returning the same value.
4. I have written client code to invoke the method of the webservice. which takes a String.
5. but when I am trying to invoke the method I am getting following exception and it's not hitting the webservice.

Infact I am using XStream along with Client/WebService.

Code goes like this for the webservice skeleton:

```
public com.url.pkg.ShowInputResponse showInput(
        com.url.pkg.ShowInput showInput) {
    // TODO : fill this with the necessary business logic
    String inputString = showInput.getInputString();
    System.out.println("INput String is :\n" + inputString);
    XStream xStream = new XStream();
    System.out.println("After XStream Declaration...");
    SOVO vo = null;
    try {
        vo = (SOVO) xStream.fromXML(inputString);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("After SOVO casting from XML");
    System.out.println(vo.getName());
    System.out.println(vo.getParams());
    // TODO: business logic
    ShowInputResponse response = new ShowInputResponse();
    response.set_return(inputString);
    return response;
}
```

My client code goes like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BasicServiceStub stub = new BasicServiceStub();
        ShowInput request = new ShowInput();
        SOVO sovo = new SOVO();
        sovo.setName("I am the post for SO");
        Map params = new HashMap();
        params.put("key1", "val1");
        params.put("key2", "val2");
        sovo.setParams(params);
        XStream xStream = new XStream();
        String soVoString = xStream.toXML(sovo);
        // System.out.println(soVoString);
        request.setInputString(soVoString);
        ShowInputResponse response = stub.showInput(request);
        System.out.println("....................................");
        System.out.println("response = " + response.get_return());
    }
```

SOVO is a simple POJO which is present at both client and webservice side.

```
public class SOVO {

    private String name;
    private Map params;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Map getParams() {
        return params;
    }

    public void setParams(Map params) {
        this.params = params;
    }

}
```

And last but most important WSDL is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:ns1="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd" xmlns:ns="http://pkg.url.com" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" targetNamespace="http://pkg.url.com">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://pkg.url.com">
            <xs:element name="showInput">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="inputString" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="showInputResponse">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="showInputRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:showInput"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="showInputResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:showInputResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="BasicServicePortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="showInput">
            <wsdl:input message="ns:showInputRequest" wsaw:Action="urn:showInput"/>
            <wsdl:output message="ns:showInputResponse" wsaw:Action="urn:showInputResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="BasicServiceSoap11Binding" type="ns:BasicServicePortType">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="showInput">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:showInput" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:binding name="BasicServiceSoap12Binding" type="ns:BasicServicePortType">
        <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="showInput">
            <soap12:operation soapAction="urn:showInput" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:binding name="BasicServiceHttpBinding" type="ns:BasicServicePortType">
        <http:binding verb="POST"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="showInput">
            <http:operation location="BasicService/showInput"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <mime:content type="text/xml" part="showInput"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <mime:content type="text/xml" part="showInput"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="BasicService">
        <wsdl:port name="BasicServiceHttpSoap11Endpoint" binding="ns:BasicServiceSoap11Binding">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/BasicService"/>
        </wsdl:port>
        <wsdl:port name="BasicServiceHttpSoap12Endpoint" binding="ns:BasicServiceSoap12Binding">
            <soap12:address location="http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/BasicService"/>
        </wsdl:port>
        <wsdl:port name="BasicServiceHttpEndpoint" binding="ns:BasicServiceHttpBinding">
            <http:address location="http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/BasicService"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

And the Stack trace for the exception I must modify :

I am not very sure if its hitting the webservice layer.

```
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: string
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:446)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:371)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:417)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
        at com.url.pkg.BasicServiceStub.showInput(BasicServiceStub.java:184)
        at com.url.pkg.Client.main(Client.java:30)
```

It looks like more its some problem with XStream desirialization. Even though SOVO is in the classpath why its happening? Am I missing something?

When I try sending XXXXX as string it tells:

> only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not X (position: START_DOCUMENT seen X... @1:1)

When i try sending "some value" it says:

> only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not s (position: START_DOCUMENT seen s... @1:1)

I am not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Can you post the WSDL and some code?

Comment: As @Thomas said, WSDL would be great...  client code as well

Comment: I would suggest making sure your web service is working correctly by testing it with the Web Services Explorer (Run -> bottom item.. you're using Eclipse I will assume).

Comment: I will post client code, skeleton and wsdl in the reply bcoz comment will be too short.Thanks for coming back and commenting Thomas/bdares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

**Test the service with another client**

Use [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) to generate a valid test request for your `showInput` method.  If you don't get any errors using this tool, you know your service is working fine.  If you *do* get an error, then you know to start digging around in your service code.

**Enable client side logging for SOAP messages**

Add these JVM options when running your client:

```
-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog
-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.showdatetime=true
-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.httpclient.wire=debug
-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.commons.httpclient=debug
```

This will let you to see the SOAP messages that get transmitted.  Pay close attention to content appearing before your start tags like the error message says.